# JQuery Validator Updated Password

Tags: jquery, validation, change-password

I have a form which have three fields

1. Old Password
2. New Password
3. Confirm Password

These fields are optional and only mandatory when user enter some text into New Password
How can i apply jQuery Validator plugin for the same.

```
       jQuery.validator.addMethod("pass2",
        function(value,element,param) {
        var op=document.forms[0].oldpass;
        var newp=document.forms[0].newpass1;
        var cp=document.forms[0].newpass2;
        if(newp.value != "" )
        {   if(element.name=="newpass2")
            {  if(cp.value!=newp.value) {return true;}
               else {return false;}

            }
            if(element.name=="oldpass")
            {   if(op.value=="") {return true;}
                else { return false;}
            }
        }
        else
             return true;
 },"");


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form1").validate({
debug:true,
    rules: {
      oldpass:
  {
    pass2:true
  },
  /*newpass1:
  {
    pass1:true
  },*/
  newpass2: {
    pass2:true

  }
    },
    messages: {
      oldpass: "Please enter a oldpass",
  //newpass1: "Please enter newpassword",
  newpass2: "Please confirm password"
    }
  });
});
```

">

Comment: You should also check this serverside. Just so you know that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [add your own validation method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod) for that.

This allows you to specify a javascript function that determines if a given input field is valid or not. In this case, the function would return false if the NewPassword is non-empty and the given field is empty.  Attach that method to your OldPassword and ConfirmPassword fields and you are done.